# Удаление столбцов HTML таблицы

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте.

Код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.delete").live("click", function(){
/* Better index-calculation from @activa */
var myIndex = $(this).closest("th").prevAll("td").length;
$(this).parents("table").find("tr").each(function(){
$(this).find("th:eq("+myIndex+")").remove();
$(this).find("td:eq("+myIndex+")").remove();
});
});
});
</script>
```

Таблица:

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
<th><a href="#" class="delete">DELETE ROW</a>COL 1</th>
<th><a href="#" class="delete">DELETE COL</a>COL 2</th>
<th><a href="#" class="delete">DELETE COL</a>COL 3</th>
<th><a href="#" class="delete">DELETE COL</a>COL 4</th>
<th><a href="#" class="delete">DELETE COL</a>COL 5</th>
<th><a href="#" class="delete">DELETE COL</a>COL 6</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>ROW 1</td>
<td>ROW 2</td>
<td>ROW 1</td>
<td>ROW 2</td>
<td>ROW 1</td>
<td>ROW 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ROW 1</td>
<td>ROW 2</td>
<td>ROW 1</td>
<td>ROW 2</td>
<td>ROW 1</td>
<td>ROW 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Задача: после клика по ссылке должен удалиться столбец, в котором эта ссылка расположена.

Что происходит при данном коде: удаляется первый столбец, потом второй, потом третий, потом четвертый, потом пятый, потом шестой. Даже если нажимать на столбцы в обратном порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

измените

```
var myIndex = $(this).closest("th").prevAll("td").length;
```

на

```
var myIndex = $('th a.delete').index(this);
```

- [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)